# How to overwrite datetime.datetime and keep it instance of datetime.date

Tags: python, datetime, module

We wrote an overwrite of datetime.datetime and datetime.date(see below)

```
TEST_TIME_DELTA = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)

class TimeTravelDateTime(datetime.datetime):
    @classmethod
    def now(cls,*args, **kwargs):
        return super(TimeTravelDateTime,cls).now(*args, **kwargs) +  globals()["TEST_TIME_DELTA"]

    @classmethod
    def utcnow(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TimeTravelDateTime, cls).utcnow(*args, **kwargs) + globals()["TEST_TIME_DELTA"]


    @classmethod
    def today(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TimeTravelDateTime, cls).today(*args, **kwargs) + globals()["TEST_TIME_DELTA"]

class TimeTravelDate(datetime.date):
    @classmethod
    def today(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TimeTravelDate, cls).today(*args, **kwargs) + globals()["TEST_TIME_DELTA"]
```

Then we did the following

```
sys.modules['datetime'].datetime = TimeTravelDateTime
sys.modules['datetime'].date = TimeTravelDate
```

But our code now fails everytime we try to add a relativedelta to our datetime.datetimes because in the code for relativedelta add method, there is a check:

```
if not isinstance(other, datetime.date):
    raise TypeError("unsupported type for add operation")
```

Where other is datetime.datetime.today().
By default, datetime.datetime is an instance of datetime.date. Also, if we **only** overwrite datetime.datetime, then datetime.datetime.today() is **still** an instance of datetime.date. Even though type(datetime.datetime.today()) = datetime.datetime

But with our overwrite of datetime.date, the isinstance check no longer passes.

This works if we only overwrite datetime.datetime, but as soon as we overwrite datetime.date, everything goes to hell.

**How can we overwrite datetime.date so that datetime.datetime is still an instance of datetime.date. ie. keep the subclass relationships from here https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#available-types (scroll down a tiny bit).**

Comment: Why not override the check instead?

Comment: the check is in relativetimedelta which is base code and used in a lot of places, we just used freezegun package instead and refactored our tests with that https://github.com/spulec/freezegun

Answer (score 0):

we just used freezegun package instead and refactored our tests with that https://github.com/spulec/freezegun